# How exactly can a speaker produce the huge number of frequencies in musi at he same time?

Tags: acoustics, frequency

I know the basics of how a speaker works, but when I think about the fact that just one sound from an instrument has many frequencies happening at once and there are other sounds such as the guitar pick, echo in he chambers, etc. AND there are many instruments and there many be delay and Echo effects added as well. So it seems impossible rocks that just a basic thing moving back  and forth can be at a given moment moving back and forth at all those frequencies at the same time.

Comment: Can you shake your hand while moving you arm?

Comment: Think about what the frequencies of the electrical current are? Are they not the same as the sounds that the microphone absorbed.  That makes the speaker move in the same fashion.

Answer (score 1):

it's superposition. all the waves add together, and that makes one complicated motion that the speaker vibrates. if it weren't for superposition of waves, none of this could happen. perhaps you would like to study the wave equation, and more about adding sine and cosine waves.

Answer (score 0):

Adding on to the above answer, let's think of *how* the speaker's motion would then be generated.  If a waveform has a time varying amplitude x(t), a voltage  $V$ is applied so that at any time t, the integral of that voltage's action on the speaker membrane yields an amplitude of x(t).  Thus, the desired waveform is realized.

A waveform may correspond to the linear combination of various frequencies, but it will always be a smooth curve.  This means that we can have "complicated" sounds being played by a simple mechanism.